# MICR Check printing precision using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, printing, micr

I am working in an **SSRS report** that is intended to print MICR checks, I am using the **MICR E13B M2** font with a font size of **13pt**, and the MICR line printed fit the gauge spots properly most of the times, however I am having a problem among several printings, every time I print a check the **start position of the MICR line is not the same as in the previous printing**, it moves a little. This is causing that many of the times my checks don’t meet the specifications of where every MICR line character must be placed. I am using an **HP LaserJet M203dw** printer with magnetic ink. I don’t have many experience with MICR checks and I haven’t been able to find a similar problem, do anyone has had a similar problem? I would appreciate any idea to troubleshot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Valentin, does the line move vertically or horizontally?

If the line is moving vertically, you must have a MICR print settings to X, Y locations in your software. Also you need to see if the printer paper stacker is holding the paper tightly and papers in it should not be lose.